# Getting Pixel value in the image

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, pixel

I am calculating the RGB values of pixels in my captured photo. I have this code

```
func getPixelColorAtLocation(context: CGContext, point: CGPoint) -> Color {

    self.context = createARGBBitmapContext(imgView.image!)

    let data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
    let dataType = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data)

    let offset = 4 * ((Int(imageHeight) * Int(point.x)) + Int(point.y))
    var color = Color()
    color.blue = dataType[offset]
    color.green = dataType[offset + 1]
    color.red = dataType[offset + 2]
    color.alpha = dataType[offset + 3]
    color.point.x = point.x
    color.point.y = point.y
```

But I am not sure what this line means in the code.

```
let offset = 4 * ((Int(imageHeight) * Int(point.x)) + Int(point.y))
```

Any help??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image is the set of pixels. In order to get the pixel at (x,y) point, you need to calculate the `offset` for that set.

If you use `dataType[0]`, it has no offset 'cos it points to the place where the pointer is. If you used `dataType[10]`, it would mean you took 10-th element from the beginning where the pointer is.

Due to the fact, we have `RGBA` colour model, you should multiply by `4`, then you need to get what offset by `x` (it will be `x`), and by `y` (it will be the `width` of the image multiplied by `y`, in order to get the necessary column) or:

```
offset = x + width * y
// offset, offset + 1, offset + 2, offset + 3  <- necessary values for you
```

Imagine, like you have a long array with values in it.

It will be clear if you imagine the implementation of two-dimensional array  in the form of one-dimensional array. It would help you, I hope.